# What does the phrase ''as such'' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

In this following context, what does the phrase ''as such'' mean?
Does it mean ''therefore''or ''in itself''?
Or does it refer something which is an antecedent?

Please, explain this to me...

Context

> What we call “chariot” has no existence apart from and independent of
> axle, wheels, shaft, etc. What we call “house” is merely a convenient
> name for stone, wood, iron, etc., put together after a certain
> fashion, so as to enclose a portion of space, but there is no separate
> house-entity **as such** in existence.

Source: Page.7
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: These are translations from the German originals and pretty badly done.

Comment: *there is no separate house-entity **as such** in existence* = ***nothing which can be properly described as a "separate house-entity"** exists*. I'd say that mostly the text is just airy-fairy waffle, but what it's saying is essentially that "a house" is just a mental construct that doesn't really "exist" as a thing in and of itself (all that *actually* exists are the component parts - bricks, tiles, windows, etc.).

Comment: @Lambie, please share this information to me...

Comment: I doubt he wrote in English: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narada_Maha_Thera

Comment: May be, but data lost, @Lambie

Answer (score 1):

–but there is no separate house-entity as such in existence.(There is no separate house-entity exactly(in terms of its meaning) in existence)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it is a play on words involving the philosophical concept of the “thing-in-itself,” which is a translation of “das ding an sich.”

I am certainly not qualified to explicate Kantian philosophy, but here is something to get you started

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thing-in-itself